# CORS Error in React Js with third party API - from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: reactjs

var requestOptions = {
method: 'GET',
headers: myHeaders,
redirect: 'follow',
};

```
  fetch("End point API API URL", requestOptions)
    .then(response =>{
      response.text();
      console.log("response payment");
      console.log(response);
    })
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that the third party API does not allow request from your site. Check with third part API provider what policy they have.